# How do I write an expression in JavaScript that invokes the function within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Here is a problem in Udacity's Object-Oriented JavaScript course that I can't seem to get past.

Write an expression that invokes the **alerter()** function in the following array, **myArray**:

```
const myArray = [ function alerter() { alert('Hello!'); } ];

myArray[0](); //my expression
```

Even though I get what I believe to be the correct result when I run the code, the auto-grader won't accept it. Any thoughts on what's going on?

Comment: That looks valid to me. I tried something similar in my browser's console and it worked as expected. Perhaps the evaluator on Udacity is not configured/programmed to handle this. Declaring the function outside and then using the named variable inside the array might help(EDIT: like Lalit's answer below). What exact error are you seeing.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```js
function alerter() { alert('Hello!'); }
const myArray = [alerter];

myArray[0](); //my expression
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine

```
const myArray = [ function () { alert('Hello!'); } ];
myArray[0]();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
const myArray = [
   function() { alert("Hello!"); },
];
myArray.forEach(function(e) {
   e();
};
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it worked for me

```
myArray[0]()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const myArray = [ function alerter() { alert('Hello!'); } ];

myArray[0](); //expression to first access the single element in myArray, then appended parentheses to invoke the internal function.
```

Comment: Yeah, I added comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem , i think they have some issue for some reason !! anyway.

the soluation is simplely: `myArray[0]();`